# Manage OSM points online

Tags: collaboration, openstreetmap, hosted

I have around 1000 points in an Excel file with coordinates and notes on them. These are customers we visit.

Now in the past I managed that list and occationally converted it to GPX to import them as favourites into [OSMand](http://osmand.net/) to have them with me (my colleges) on the offline-OSM-maps on the tablet.

Now I would like to be able to manage those points online. So everyone on my team would be able to add new points and add notes to the existing ones.

Is there an online source that allows to manage points with OSM as map and login so not everyone can see the points? Something like "My Places" of Google Maps.

There must be the possibility to add text to the points and each point must have a name on them in the map, not only the nameless point on the map.

Comment: Like a [private OSM server](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8462/can-i-make-a-private-osm-with-user-access-validation-and-custome-notations)?

Comment: Wow, didn't know that was possible. But no. Way too much work. I search for a site that does that and don't want to set up my own. And I only need my points being private.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. I already expected that. Sorry I don't have a suggestion for that.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **[uMap](http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/)**. It is an online tool for creating maps, based on OpenStreetMap.

You can draw markers, lines and areas on the map. These can be given names, descriptions, icons and colours.

There are a number of different background layers to choose from.

It has privacy options, so you can control who is able to see the map. You can add more users as editors, so they can add or edit points.

It has options for importing and exporting data in a variety of formats, including GPX.

There are several online instances of uMap, the main one is at http://umap.openstreetmap.fr/en/

uMap is free and open source, so you could download the code and set it up on your own server if you want. Some more details: [uMap on OpenStreetMap wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/UMap)